# Check if a string can be converted to list Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to check if a string like `foo = "[1,2,3]"` can be converted to a list `foo = [1,2,3]` but the problem is sometimes `foo = "[1,2,3]."` or `foo = "[1,2,3"` or `foo = "[test]" # it should be "['test']" to get accepted` ...etc.

My approach to solving this:

```
if isinstance(literal_eval(foo), list): # if its literal_eval is a list
    foo = literal_eval(foo) # then make it a list
```

so when I use `isinstance(literal_eval(foo), list)` it raises error if foo was something like `foo = "[1,2,3]."` instead of returning a bool `True` or `False`.

Is there any possible way to check if my string can be a list before actually converting it to a list?

Comment: Is your code just meant to check if the conversion to list can be achieved (i.e., return True/False) or is it meant to return a list (if conversion can be achieved). If the latter, what would you return if conversion cannot be done?

Comment: if conversion can't be done I will leave it as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`try`/`except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) block:

```
import ast
def check(foo):
    try:
        return isinstance(ast.literal_eval(foo), list)
    except SyntaxError:
        return False

check('[1,2,3].')
# False

check('1')
# False

check('[1, 2]')
# True
```

Comment: IMO if we use `try...except` it's better to return eather a list or `None`

Answer (score 0):

Use `ast.literal_eval` with try catch:

```py
try:
    foo = literal_eval(foo)
    if not isinstance(foo, list):
        raise TypeError("Not a list")
except:
    print("Could not safely create a list")
```

Comment: I think OP wants the other way around ;)